# adsense code not displaying ads

Tags: javascript, wordpress, adsense

I have a wordpress site named www.onlinegreatway.com. In my site, the adsense code is not working. I didn't violate any policies of google adsense. The ads are not displaying in homepage as well as in single post page.
But if I type a wrong url like www.onlinegreatway.com/abcdef, then again main page opens with title "page not found"(I think it is because I didn't create any 404.php) and at this time, the ads are displaying. What is the problem?

Comment: Is the add showing only in 404 pages. If yes I think you placed the code in the wrong file. Try placing the ads in Header.php and check if its coming.

Comment: @kiranvj , no it is not displaying yet. I tried placing inside and outside the <head></head> tag. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> www.onlinegreatway.com/abcdef, then again main page opens with title
>   "page not found"(I think it is because I didn't create any 404.php)

This is because the url format www.onlinegreatway.com/abcdef is handled by .htaccess file wordpress created.

Comment: Oh, yes it is. But the main problem is still the same. If I type www.onlinegreatway.com, the ads donot work. But if I type www.onlinegreatway.com/fasdfa , ads are displyed. Please visit yourself @kiranvj.

Comment: There is also problem with facebook share. When I share any of the link of my post, the title of the post apprears but the description  of the home page appears.